# How to get rid of the first letter from row names

Tags: r, dataframe

[In this data frame I am trying to remove the letter S from in all the row names, so instead of S14 it would just be 14. Any advice?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFq5G.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rownames(df) <- gsub("S", "", rownames(df))
```